# mojoPortal Process after Recover Password

Tags: c#, asp.net, mojoportal

The current process after hitting the submit button (in recoverPassword.aspx) is when a valid username is entered it will show a sentence that "email has been sent...", and the textbox will disappear and when an invalid username is entered the textbox will remain on the screen.

My question is where can I do the setting whereby doesn't matter valid or invalid username is entered, it will remain the textbox on the screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll see about changing the page to show the textbox. Why is it that you need the textbox to be there after submitting?